# My app keeps crashing when I try to send an object via putExtra in recyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to send an object from a recyclerView to another Activity but the app keeps crashing. When I use a Toast on the clickListener, the object passed is read all right but when I use putExtra it crashes. Can someone help me with this?

Below is my MainActivity where my recyclerView is, followed by the Adapter and the activity I want the object to go

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener{

    var dayList : MutableList<Day> = mutableListOf()
    var adapter = DayAdapter(dayList)
    private var cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    private lateinit var dateSetListener: DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val database = SDatabase(this)
        val repository = ListRepository(database)
        val factory = ListItemsViewModelFactory(repository)




        rv_grocery_list_day.adapter = adapter
        rv_grocery_list_day.layoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true)

        val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(ListItemsViewModel::class.java)

        viewModel.getAllDays().observe(this, androidx.lifecycle.Observer {
            adapter.days = it
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })

        adapter.setOnClickListener(object : DayAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
            override fun onItemClick(position: Int, model: Day) {
        //        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "$model clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

               val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, ListActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DAY, dayList[position])
              startActivity(intent)
            }
        })

        dateSetListener = DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)

            val myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.getDefault())
            val date = sdf.format(cal.time).toString()
            val day = Day(date, 0)
            dayList.add(day)
            viewModel.upsertDay(day)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            rv_grocery_list_day.scrollToPosition(0)
        }

        fab_add_day.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        when(view!!.id) {
            R.id.fab_add_day -> {
                DatePickerDialog(this@MainActivity,
                    dateSetListener,
                    cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show()
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        var EXTRA_DAY = "extra_day"
    }

}
```

```
class DayAdapter(
    var days: List<Day>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DayAdapter.DayViewHolder>(){

    private var onClickListener: OnItemClickListener? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DayViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.shopping_day, parent, false)
        return DayViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DayViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val curDay = days[position]

        holder.tvDate.text = curDay.day
        holder.cost.text = curDay.cost.toString()
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
            if(onClickListener != null){
                onClickListener!!.onItemClick(position, curDay)
            }
        }
    }

    fun setOnClickListener(onClickListener: OnItemClickListener) {
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return days.size
    }

    inner class DayViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val tvDate: TextView = itemView.tv_date
        val cost: TextView = itemView.tv_cost_shopping


    }

    interface OnItemClickListener{
        fun onItemClick(position: Int, model: Day)

    }


}
```

```
class ListActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    private var dayModel: Day? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list)

        val database = SDatabase(this)
        val repository = ListRepository(database)
        val factory = ListItemsViewModelFactory(repository)

        val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(ListItemsViewModel::class.java)

        val itemsList = mutableListOf<Item>()

        if(intent.hasExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_DAY)){
            dayModel = intent.getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_DAY) as Day

        }
```

Comment: I think it is because of you call `dayList[position]` when daylist is still empty. But to make sure, please show us the error log

Comment: By the error given, I think you are right but I don't know how to fix it.

```
2021-01-14 17:04:54.744 4445-4445/com.henriquetavolaro.feira E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.henriquetavolaro.feira, PID: 4445
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 0
```

Comment: @HenriqueTavolaro from the error, It means that your dayList is empty (with 0 elements) but you're trying to get the item at position 2 (which doesn't exist) leading to an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Also add this error message to your question

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` from this line inside `onItemClick`:

```
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DAY, dayList[position])
```

This is because you are trying to get an item from the MutableList `dayList` in a position that doesn't exists.

Your adapter dataset is not in sync with the dataset you are trying to get the clicked position from.

You are updating the adapter dataset here without updating `dayList`, hence your RecyclerView will have more items than what is in `dayList`.

```
    viewModel.getAllDays().observe(this, androidx.lifecycle.Observer {
        adapter.days = it
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    })
```

To solve this, you should update `dayList` instead of reassigning the `days` property directly.

```
    viewModel.getAllDays().observe(this, androidx.lifecycle.Observer {
        dayList.clear()
        dayList.addAll(it)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    })
```

Also consider making `days` inside your adapter private and immutable to avoid such issues.

```
class DayAdapter(private val days: List<Day>):
RecyclerView.Adapter<DayAdapter.DayViewHolder>(){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving the model for the position where the item clicked, you can use that like below

```
adapter.setOnClickListener(object : DayAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
            override fun onItemClick(position: Int, model: Day) {
        //        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "$model clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

               val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, ListActivity::class.java)
                //intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DAY, dayList[position])
               intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DAY, model)
              startActivity(intent)
            }
        })
```